# How to swap the content of 2 disks?

Tags: hard-drive, clone

I have 2 SSDs disk, one with 250GB and another with 500GB.
Both with Operating System (Windows 10 and 7), software and personal files and settings.
Both with around 100GB occupied space.
There is also a Linux partition on one of them but I don't mind losing it.

How can I swap the content of both disks and still be able to boot from them?
I mean without needing to reinstall Windows nor the software.
By just using some software such as Acronis, Easeus, Paragon, Clonezilla or AOMEI.

There are many tutorials on how to clone one disk but the destination gets erased.
I guess I'll need to create intermediates images of both disks and keep them on the larger one.
What do you advise?

Regards.

Comment: add partitions on harddrives and try cloning

Comment: [There are hundreds of HDD Docking stations that allow you to duplicate a drives.](https://www.bing.com/search?q=hdd+cloning+station&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN)  Use of one of those.  You would have to obviously format one of the drives, after you backup the data, before you duplicated the other drive.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you should back up your files on a separate hard drive before starting any of this, but it seems that you only have these two drives to work with, so here goes...

1. Create an image of the larger one and store it on itself. Then
   create an image of the smaller one and store it on the larger.
2. Boot Linux from a live CD, DVD or USB. You can just use a
   lightweight Linux distro like [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htmkqs7I8eynKQ&bvm=bv.108538919,d.dmo). There are plenty of
   tutorials on how to create a live CD or USB.
3. Open up the terminal and enter `lsblk`. Identify the smaller disk,
   which should be labeled "sda", "sdb", "sdc", etc.
4. Mount the partition containing your images `mount /dev/sdx#`, where
   'x' is the disk containing the image and '#' is the partition
   number. You should be able to identify which one based on the size
   output by `lsblk`.
5. Enter the command `dd if="path to disk image" of=/dev/sdx` where 'x'
   is the identifier of the target disk.
6. Make sure everything in step 5 is correct, hit enter, wait a few
   hours and repeat in the other direction after copying the smaller
   disk image file back to the original source disk.

Comment: I think that will only copy files but no MBR and I guess Windows won't be able to boot, isn't it?

Comment: Nope everything will be copied. Check out the link below for some warnings and info.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_cloning#Using_dd

Comment: What software would you use to create the images?
Does the 'dd' method work if the drives have different sizes?